# NodeJS setting up wildcard routes or url rewrite

Tags: javascript, node.js, wildcard

I have a simple route thing like this in node using connect (source/routes.js):

```
exports.routes = function(app) {
    app.get('/data', function(req, res, params) {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/plain' });
            res.write('Authenticated: ' + connect.session.auth + '\n');
            res.end('app.get /data');
    });
}
```

Starting the app (app.js):

```
var routes = require('connect');
var routes = require('./source/routes');

var server = connect.createServer(
    connect.cookieParser(),
    connect.session({ secret: 'justmeknowsthis', cookie: { maxAge: config.data.sessionTimeout }}),
    connect.router(routes.routes)
);

server.listen(3000);
```

What I want to be able to do is:

```
app.get('/data*', function(...
```

I determine what data to return by parsing the url.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, the router middleware has been removed from Connect, so you can either use Express or make your own router to be safer for the future ( see this commit: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/commit/2ca7ec3ff64cb7600bfd029233228236bf048671 ).

If you choose to use Express, you can pass in a regular expression for the route (more info here: http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing), but I would use something like this instead (for your specific case):

```
app.get('/data/:type', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Received ' + req.params.type + ' data');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems like a good idea good to roll my own stuff for now. You know the reason for removing router?

Comment: Yes I actually asked a guy from Learnboost (the Mongoose author) and he said TJ removed it from the middleware since it was becoming too much customized in order to suite Express.

Comment: Btw Asken you can look at the source code from Express or Flatiron, to extract the router part. ( #inspiration )

Comment: It should be: 'Received ' + req.params.type + ' data'

Comment: @poshaughnessy yup sorry about that, I guess I was in a hurry when I wrote the answer or something.